# Javascript increment value faster with mouse hold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that adds 1 to a value every time I click on a button:

```
<script>
    function incrementValue(id) {
       var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
       value = value + 1;
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="incrementValue('skill_1')"> add </button><br>
<span id=skill_1>0</span>
```

However I want to adjust it so that if I hold down the mouse button, it'll repeat so I don't have to keep pressing it over and over.

Any way to do that using javascript? Or would jquery suit?

Comment: There are the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` event handlers. I'm sure you can do something with that: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousedown Perhaps also look at `onmouseout`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use the `mousedown` event to start a timeout (which is the delay before the incremental count starts) and an interval (which does the repeated counting). You'll also need a `mouseup` and `mouseleave` handler to remove both of those timers. Try this:

```js
var timeout, interval;

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.add'), function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    var id = button.dataset.target;
    incrementValue(id);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        incrementValue(id);
      }, 50);    
    }, 300);
  });
  
  button.addEventListener('mouseup', clearTimers);
  button.addEventListener('mouseleave', clearTimers); 
  
  function clearTimers() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});

function incrementValue(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var value = parseInt(el.textContent, 10);
  document.getElementById(id).textContent = ++value;
}
```

```html
<button class="add" data-target="skill_1">add</button><br />
<span id="skill_1">0</span>
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks

Comment: Watch out though. If you mouse down over the button, drag the mouse outside the button, then mouse up, it will increment forever.

Comment: @user1022585 I edited the answer with a simple solution to avoid incrementing forever by listening to two mouse events `'mouseup mouseleave'`

Comment: @DJDaveMark Very good point, thanks for letting me know. Just FYI I amended your edit slightly as you can't assign multiple events in `addEventListener()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I forgot to take my jQuery googles off, and you beat me editing my own edit.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need 3 event handler:

1. `mousedown` that will call a function, that will call itself with a timeout (`continuosIncerment`) while the mouse button is pressed.
2. `mouseup` that will clear the timeout when the button is released.
3. `mouseleave` that clears the timeout when the mouse leaves the button area.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const skill_1 = document.querySelector('#skill_1');
let value = 0;
let timer;

function continuosIncerment() {
  skill_1.innerHTML = ++value;
  
  timer = setTimeout(continuosIncerment, 200);
}

function timeoutClear() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', continuosIncerment);

btn.addEventListener('mouseup', timeoutClear);

btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', timeoutClear);
```

```html
<button id="btn"> add </button><br>
<span id="skill_1">0</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading the value from the HTML, then writing it back, it's easier to hold the value in a variable, increment it, then write it out.

Did you know you can do this with a simple HTML spinner?

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a solution like this: on mouse down event starts a repeating timer that triggers your function and it stops when the mouse up event occurs.

```js
var inter = null;

function setInter(){   
    inter=setInterval(incrementValue, 500);
}

function unsetInter(){
    clearInterval(inter);
}

function incrementValue() {
   var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('skill_1').innerHTML);
   value = value + 1;
   document.getElementById('skill_1').innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<button 
onmousedown="setInter()"
onmouseup="unsetInter()"> add </button>
<br>
<span id=skill_1>0</span>
```

Comment: Doens't work....

Comment: Edit, now it works, sorry